# Can I run Fallout : New Vegas without a video card?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I was looking at my laptop's specifications ( an Hp probook ) and it doesn't have a video card. Can I still get and run Fallout : New Vegas? Not the ultimate edition.

Comment: Is it a good idea to run this game on a business laptop like an HP probook?

Comment: Voting to leave open. The linked question is great for contemporary games but doesn't cover very old games with an integrated graphics card and a CPU well ahead of the specs.

Comment: Your computer can't display anything without a graphics card. It either has an integrated one or some components on the motherboard acting as one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a graphics adapter, your computer won't be able to display anything on the monitor, so gaming would be impossible. Luckily, modern PCs all have a graphics adapter.

In your case, since the PC doesn't have a graphics card, the graphics adapter would be an IGP (Integrated Graphics Processor) which is built into the CPU. You can easily find out which IGP is included in your CPU (assuming you know what CPU is built in your PC, of course).

From here on, all you need to do is compare the IGP with whatever GPU meets the game's requirements. For instance, [**here**](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GeForce-6800-GT-vs-Intel-HD-530-Desktop-Skylake/m20452vsm33102) I compared a GeForce 6800 GT to an Intel HD 530 (included in the Intel i7 6700 series CPU). The HD 530 appears to be more than fast enough for New Vegas.

**Keep in mind** that this is no guarantee the game will run. Some games may refuse to run on newer hardware even though they could. Luckily, both Steam and GoG offer refunds in case the game doesn't run.

---

As to your comment:

> Is it a good idea to run this game on a business laptop like an HP probook?

If it's not designed for gaming, it's usually not a good idea to run games on it. For multiple reasons:

- Your laptop's keyboard may not support pressing more than 3 keys simultaneously, while the game may require 4 or more simultaneous keys being pressed.
- Your laptop's cooling may not be designed for high-performance situations (especially for extended periods of time). This can cause unexpected reboots and even damage your PC in the worst case.
- Your laptop could perform better with the same specs, if it was designed for gaming. For instance, by including 2 smaller memory modules in a dual-channel configuration, compared to a single big one (twice the memory bandwidth).

Comment: As a side note: Fallout 3 and New Vegas are known for crashing during VATS on PCs with more than 2 CPU cores. This can be fixed by disabling multicore processing in the `.ini` file. The fix is apparently included in the GoG version by default.